# AngularJS Cordova Media Doesn't Always Play Next Song

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using the Ionic Framework with AngularJS and the ngCordova Media Plugin: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/media/

I currently have two functions in my controller;

1. Play - this function plays the chosen media src

   ```
     $scope.play = function(src) {
           media = $cordovaMedia2.newMedia(src, null, null, mediaStatusCallback);
           media.play(); 
           $scope.isPlaying = true;
           $ionicLoading.hide();

       }
     }
   ```
2. Next Song - this function gets the src of next song in the list by looking up the index of current song object and choosing the next object in the list.

   ```
   $scope.nextSong = function (song_id) {
           var index = $scope.allsongs.indexOf(song_id);
           if(index >= 0 && index < $scope.allsongs.length - 1) {
              $scope.nextsongid = $scope.allsongs[index + 1]
              $scope.playMusic($scope.nextsongid);  //the playMusic function just looks up the src of the song and parses to the play function
           }
   }
   ```

Here is the playMusic function which is called above:

```
    $scope.playMusic = function(music_id)
{
    myService.getSongInfo(music_id)
    .then(function(data){
      $scope.cursong = data.results;
      $scope.play($scope.cursong.src);
    });
};
```

And in my template, the next button just calls the nextSong function like so with the current song ID:

```
<div class="next" ng-click="nextSong('{{cursong.id}}')"></div>
```

The problem I'm facing is that when i press the next button first time, it plays the next song but when i press it again, it plays the same song again. It seems the 'currsong' value is not updated.

This is what the 'allsongs' array looks like:

```
["1631922", "1502059", "1365874", "1607940", "1251204", "1233296", "1151847", "1119737", "1086438", "1078140", "1068172", "1065312", "845339", "799161", "316293", "306073", "299817", "1603940"]
```

**Update: I tried using an interval**

I have an interval function which skips to next song when the time has reached the duration. I call the nextsong function there and it works perfectly.

```
    $scope.Timer = $interval(function () {

$scope.cursongduration = $scope.cursong.duration;
$scope.cursongid = $scope.cursong.id;


if($scope.currduration >= $scope.cursongduration){
    $scope.nextSong($scope.cursongid);
    }, 1000);
};
```

So my question is why calling nextSong through the template button work as well? To me it seems like the cursong.id is not updated in the template after 1 time for some odd reason. I have also tried using cursongid variable which is set in the interval in the template button but no luck:

```
<div class="next" ng-click="nextSong('{{cursongid}}')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by creating a new function 'PlayNextSong' which stores $scope.cursong.id into a new scope 'cursongid' and then calls the nextSong function. This works fine in my case.

The function:

```
$scope.playNextSong = function() {

    $scope.cursongid = $scope.cursong.id;
    $scope.nextSong($scope.cursongid);

}
```

The button:

```
<div class="next" ng-click="playNextSong()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn`t in cordova or media plugin, when you play the song you have to update the `$scope.cursong.id` so the next click can know what is the current song.

```
$scope.play = function(src) {
        $scope.cursong.id = src;
        media = $cordovaMedia2.newMedia(src, null, null, mediaStatusCallback);
        media.play(); 
        $scope.isPlaying = true;
        $ionicLoading.hide();

    }
  }
```

I`m assuming you have declared the `$scope.cursong.id` somewhere in your script.

Comment: This is done in the playMusic function $scope.cursong is updated with the info about the song including it's id and src. Please see updated question with the code for playMusic.

Comment: Can you share some example of return of the "data.results"

Comment: Object { id: 1251204, status: "complete", stream_only: "yes"}
streaming_url: "https://cloudfrontlink"

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that when i press the next button first time, it plays the next song but when i press it again, it plays the same song again. It seems the 'currsong' value is not updated after the second time.

Comment: try to use this line in the nextSong function `var index = $scope.allsongs.indexOf(String(song_id));`

Comment: song_id is already a string. Same issue with that line - it plays the next song fine the first time and then when the next song button is pressed again, it plays the same next song.

Comment: Please see updated question. Calling nextSong works fine during interval function but with the template button, still no luck.